# How to access data most effectively in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a tiny test dataset for students university applications in different majors
It looks like this

```
0   35377       female  Chemistry   False
1   56105       male    Physics     True
2   31441       female  Chemistry   False
3   51765       male    Physics     True
4   53714       female  Physics     True
```

`shape is 500,4`

I need to get the admission rate for females and solved it now in three different ways. Each of them return the correct result.

**DONE**

Using group by

````py
female_admitted_rate = df.groupby('gender').get_group('female')[df['admitted'] == True].count()/len(df.groupby('gender').get_group('female'))```

```python
[OUT]
student_id    0.287938
gender        0.287938
major         0.287938
admitted      0.287938
dtype: float64
````

Using plain pandas

```py
len(df[(df['gender']=='female') & (df['admitted'])])/(len(df[df['gender']=='female']))

[Out] 0.28793774319066145
```

Using query

```py
len(df.query("gender == 'female' & admitted"))/len(df.query("gender == 'female'"))

[Out] 0.28793774319066145
```

**QUESTIONS**

- What would you use to get this information?
- Is there a special
  advantage for one of the shown approaches?
- Is there one approach
  what makes absolutely not sense to you guys?
- Is there an perticular
  calculation performance benefit by using one of the three above the
  others when it comes to big data sets?

Comment: Using the `time` module, you can check out the differences, in average.

Comment: `df[['gender','admitted']].groupby('gender').mean()` will give you stats for all genders.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with premature optimization.  Test each method if performance becomes an issue, but the optimal solution may depend on exactly *how* your data grows (e.g., run more times vs on a much larger df).

Comment: thanks guys for all you input and different views. It very helped me to get a clear pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only need [`DataFrame.loc[]`](http://%20These%20times%20are%20for%20the%20sample%20data%20frame%20and%20performance%20could%20vary%20greatly%20depending%20on%20the%20size%20of%20your%20data%20frame.%20Although%20I%20honestly%20believe%20that%20the%20method%20I%20propose%20will%20be%20the%20fastest%20in%20most%20cases,%20in%20addition%20to%20providing%20a%20clean%20and%20simple%20syntax) + [`Series.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
df.loc[df['gender'].eq('female'), 'admitted'].mean()
```

`True` is interpreted as `1` and `False` as `0` by `Series.mean`

You can check with `timeit`

```
%%timeit
df.loc[df['gender'].eq('female'), 'admitted'].mean()
1.16 ms ± 66.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
len(df[(df['gender']=='female') & (df['admitted'])])/(len(df[df['gender']=='female']))
3.45 ms ± 428 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df.groupby('gender').get_group('female')[df['admitted'] == True].count()/len(df.groupby('gender').get_group('female'))
10.3 ms ± 718 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
len(df.query("gender == 'female' & admitted"))/len(df.query("gender == 'female'"))
11.1 ms ± 604 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

These times are for the sample `DataFrame` I think performance could vary greatly depending on the **shape** of your `DataFrame`. Although I honestly believe that the method I propose will be the fastest in most cases, in addition to providing a clean and simple syntax.

Comment: thank you very much ansev. you really teached me some things here!